# Why is there no liaison for the second person singular?

Tags: prononciation, conjugaison, liaisons

Why is there no liaison for the second person singular, that is, as between e.g. 'aies' and 'été' in 'que tu aies été'?

Is it a peculiarity of the second person singular?

Or is there some more general principle, of which this phenomenon is an application?

**BACKGROUND**

For 'être' see:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vIjoHatxZt8

For 'avoir' see:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8x7RCaQMopk

The pattern seems fairly consistent.  For conditional passé of 'avoir' there is liaison for every person and number except for the second person singular.

[image]

Comment: Not sure. I'm not even sure whether that _liaison_ would be forbidden or optional. I would pin it _again_ on usage :-) It sounds good without the _liaison_, but it doesn't sound too bad with it either. The form is not super frequent, so I'm not sure what we would say more.

Comment: @Frank. You seem to be confirming that it is an arbitrary thing about the second person singular? / Someone might come up with some interesting historical reason for it.

Comment: Yes - but I am really throwing my arms up in the air rather than confirming :-) I'm not shocked by either, and it is not super common, so I'm having a hard time deciding one way or the other.

Comment: C'est une liaison qui n'est ni interdite ni obligatoire, elle est donc facultative. Déjà souvent cité ici cette [page de wikipedia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liaison_en_fran%C3%A7ais#Liaison_obligatoire) qui est bien faite et voir aussi [ici](http://research.jyu.fi/phonfr/91.html). Pas de différence à faire entre les personnes, ensuite ce sont des questions d'habitudes (et les habitudes évoluent).

Comment: [This link](http://www.spellandsound.com/french-liaisons/) has proved use useful before.

Comment: @Laure. Thank you. After going through the materials you link, I may have following-up questions.

Comment: @Catomic Did you check all the [liaisons tagged questions](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/liaisons) on FL? Sometimes the questions are very specific but answers are rarely specific to one case and one way or another it might well be that all the rules have already been mentioned.

Comment: Anyway forget the link in your question, the guy is inconsistent in his liaisons and no rules can be drawn from the way he speaks. I'm not saying what he says is wrong *per se* but from a teaching point of view he should treat all optional liaisons within one conjugation table the same way since he is addressing learners of French as a foreign language who have to go by rules and not by force of habit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cette liaison n'est pas **interdite**, mais **facultative** :

> Les liaisons facultatives sont des liaisons qui ne sont ni
>   obligatoires, ni interdites: elles sont conseillées. La seule
>   véritable règle qui régit les liaisons facultatives est celle des
>   niveaux de langue en fonction de la situation de communication dans
>   laquelle on se trouve.
>
> Ainsi, on remarque que plus le registre est soutenu, plus les liaisons
>   facultatives sont nombreuses et inversement que plus il est familier,
>   plus les liaisons facultatives sont rarifiées. L’usage conseille donc
>   de faire davantage de liaisons facultatives dans un contexte formel de
>   communication (à la lecture par exemple).
>
> - Extrait de [*Les liaisons facultatives*](http://www.latl.unige.ch/safran/data/phono/mod8/liaison/principe/3_facult/)

A l'oral, beaucoup de personnes omettent de faire certaines liaisons. Cela n'est pas dérangeant dans le cas de liaisons facultatives, mais peu rendre la diction moins élégante notamment dans le cas d'un langage soutenu.

J'aurais **personnellement** tendance à préférer faire la liaison entre *aies* et *été* dans *que tu aies été*.